# Error when I export to text file

Tags: c#, text, ascii

I have a C# desktop application. I need to generate a file (that I read from sql database). In the string values such as name I want to use chars like Ã. I changed the regional setting to standard and choose Romanian format but in my text files I have char Ă.
I have more chars that have to be used:

- Instead of Ş  I need  ª
- Instead of Ţ  I need  Þ

I don't know what should I modify to replace these chars.
Can somebody help me to generate my file using this chars?

Comment: Can you give us a code example and a database table structure?

Comment: user1577242, did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at this picture

[image]

you'll find the char numbers you need. so now what you need to do is this: if you read from DB to `string s;`:

```
int CharNumToReplace;
int CharNumThatReplace the former;
s.Replace((char)(CharNumToReplace), (char)(CharNumThatReplace))
```

i actually don't see the characters you need here but in debug mode you can find their value by placing a watch `(int)myVal`

here:
[image]